# Wordpress Playlist show length of all titles

Tags: php, wordpress, audio, mp3, playlist

I have Wordpress Posts which contain the embedded audio playlist. Songs are all displayed and play ok. But here are a few where the title length is not being displayed beside the title. The DOM node:

```
<div class="wp-playlist-item-length">X:XX</div>
```

is not rendered for them. So the result looks like this:
[image: Playlist with missing song lengths]
But as you can see, when the title is being played, the length is shown correctly on the right of the audio player.

I did not add extra code for the player, just use the embedded functionality. 
I found this link [from the developer pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_underscore_playlist_templates/). And I assume it must have sth. do with this line of code:

```
<# if ( data.meta.length_formatted ) { #>
    <div class="wp-playlist-item-length">{{ data.meta.length_formatted }}</div>
    <# } #>
```

What am I missing here? I can't see a difference with the other songs for which the title length is rendered.
THX

[EDIT: The difference seems to be, that the files, for which the length is being displayed are stored with "Filetype: MP3 (audio/mpeg) and a bitrate in kb/s CBR. The ones with no length are just stored with Filetype: MP3. Is there any way to get the length from these too (because the length is shwon when being played..)]